# EF or Linq: Get list that includes another list but filter the second list where its property is true

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two Classes:

```
public Case() 
{ 
  public IList<CaseThirdParty> CaseThirdParties { get; private set; }
}

public CaseThirdParty() 
{
  public bool Received_Claim { get; private set; }
}
```

I am using ef core to get all Cases but only get
`CaseThirdParties` where `Received_Claim` is `True`, here is the query:

```
await _context.Cases.Include(c => c.CaseThirdParties)
              .Where(c => c.CaseThirdParties.Any(c => c.Received_Claim))
              .ToArrayAsync();
```

Or

```
await _context.Cases.Include(c => c.CaseThirdParties)
              .Where(c => c.CaseThirdParties.Where(c => c.Received_Claim).Count>0)
              .ToArrayAsync();
```

But it retrieves `CaseThirdParties` where `Received_Claim` is `flase`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ef core 5.0 or later you can use Filtered include

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include

like this:

```
await _context.Cases.Include(case => case.CaseThirdParties.Where(c => c.Received_Claim))
              .ToArrayAsync();
```

if not you have to create an anonymous object with Case and CaseThirdParties like this:

```
await _context.Cases.Where(case => case.CaseThirdParties.Any(case3rd => case3rd.Received_Claim))
              .Select(case =>
              {
                Case = case,
                CaseThirdParties = case.CaseThirdParties.Where(case3rd => case3rd.Received_Claim)
              })
              .ToArrayAsync();
```